# Undefined connection variable in PHP

Tags: php

I've got a php script as follows:

```
function addPost(BlogPost $item, $tags) {
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', '***', '***') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('jschaible1') or die(mysql_error());

        $queryString = "insert into BlogPost values ( null, '" . $item->Title . "', '" . $item->Body . "', " . "now());";

        $result = mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());

        $dbResult = mysql_query('select * from blogpost where Title = "' . $item->Title . '";') or die(mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbResult)) {
            $tableID = $row['BlogPostID'];
        }

        foreach($tags as $t) {
            $queryString = "insert ignore into Tag values('" . strtolower($t) . "');";
            mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());

            $queryString = "insert into blogposttag values (" . $tableID . ", '" . strtolower($t) . "');";
            mysql_query($queryString) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        echo $connection;
        mysql_close($connection) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

The function is being called like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $errors = '';

    if (!isset($_SESSION['dadfg6d5f6df54']))
        header('Location:admin.php');
    else {
        include('Classes.php');
        include('mySql.php');
        include('utils.php');

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            if ($_POST['Title'] == '') {
                $errors = 'Post must have a title!';
            }
            else if ($_POST['PostBody'] == '') {
                $errors = 'Post must be something!';
            }
            else if (strlen($_POST['PostBody']) < 10) {
                $errors = "Write something substantial, c'mon!";
            }
            else if ($_POST['Tags'] == '') {
                $errors = "At least one tag must be entered";
            }
            else {
                $newPost = new BlogPost(NULL, sanitize($_POST['Title']), sanitize($_POST['PostBody']), NULL);

                $newPost->Title = addEmoticons($newPost->Title);
                $newPost->Body = addEmoticons($newPost->Body);

                $tags = str_replace(',', '', $_POST['Tags']);
                $tags = str_replace(';', '', $tags);
                $tags = explode(' ', $tags);

                error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                addPost($newPost, $tags) or die();

                $errors = 'Post added successfully';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

When it gets to mysql_close(), the page just stops executing and I get a blank page. This is really frustrating me, I don't understand at all why it's happening, especially seeing as how the echo on the PREVIOUS line puts out "resource id#6". I get no error message, just a blank page! Please help!

Comment: Turn on error reporting. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` And also post how you are calling the function

Comment: `mysql_close()` will return FALSE on failure, and if the script has already determined it doesn't need the resource any longer, it closes it implicitly before your explicit call.  Therefore, there's nothing to close, it returns false, and triggers your `die()` call. Just remove the `die()`.

Comment: I tried removing the die(). The page just breaks and I get a white page

Comment: then turn on error reporting. A blank white page in PHP means a fatal error you are not seeing.

Comment: I put that code just above where I'm calling the function. Still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function has no return value. It therefore returns `NULL` which [evaluates as a "falsy" value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). Since you follow it with an `or die()` call, the false evaluation triggers the `or die()` and  terminates your script.

```
// Don't do this:
addPost($newPost, $tags) or die();

// Do this:
addPost($newPost, $tags);
```

In the end of your function, you could `return TRUE`, but it is entirely unnecessary unless you wish to return a value based on the success or failure of your post addition.  The way you have it, the `die()` is just causing undue harm.  Since all the potential failing points in your function are already going to terminate the script on error, there is no great purpose to returning `TRUE`. Just remove the `die()` after the function call.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you so much! I don't remember what initially happened, but I was having another error and I began throwing "or die()" on everything trying to make it work. I'm still a little new to php, and I guess I think "or die()" is the equivalent of a "try{}catch{}" in C-style languages. Thank you!

Comment: @Jack PHP [has its own try/catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) but not all language aspects throw exceptions.  The `or die()` method of debugging is an unfortunate holdover inherited from Perl habits.  Instead of that, I recommend always returning database calls to a variable and then testing the variable.  `$result = mysql_query(....); if (!$result) {echo mysql_error();} else { do_what_you_wanted() }`

Comment: Thank you. This is for a school project, and they focus mainly on the pure php side, we only briefly touch on the database connectivity parts. I'm not all that familiar with the best practices and things like that when it comes to this aspect of PHP.